# dbpedia fetch entitites in language other than english

Tags: sparql, owl, wikipedia, dbpedia, foaf

I'm trying to extract entity dictionary contains person name etc. from dbpedia using sparql.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    ?person a owl:Person .

    ?person dbpprop:name ?name . FILTER(lang(?name) = "en")
}
```

The query above did succeed, but when I change the language name to `fr`, there is nothing to fetch.

How can I fetch names in other languages?

Moreover, why can't I filter language  using query below?

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    ?person a owl:Person .
    ?person dbpprop:language "English"
    ?person dbpprop:name ?name . 
}
// this query returns nothing
```

I tried to fetch all languages using

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lanName
WHERE {
    ?person a owl:Person .
    ?person dbpprop:language ?lanName .
}
```

and the result set contains `English`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter based on the language of the value of the property.  Not *every* property will have values in different languages, but some properties will.  It seems, from your example, that **dbpprop:name** doesn't have values in every language. You may find more values in other languages if you look on the other language specific DBpediae.

However, for something like a name, you'll probably get multi-language results if you use the **rdfs:label** property.  For instance, to get the names of Barack Obama, Daniel Webster, and Johnny Cash in Russian, you could do:

```sql
select ?label {
  values ?person { dbpedia:Johnny_Cash dbpedia:Barack_Obama dbpedia:Daniel_Webster }
  ?person rdfs:label ?label .
  filter langMatches(lang(?label),"ru")
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Flabel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fperson%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AJohnny_Cash%20dbpedia%3ABarack_Obama%20dbpedia%3ADaniel_Webster%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22ru%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

As an aside, note the use of [langMatches](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches) rather than equality for matching language tags.  This is usually a better approach, because it will correctly handle the different language tags within a language  For example (from the SPARQL specification), you can find both of the French literals:

```
"Cette Série des Années Soixante-dix"@fr .
"Cette Série des Années Septante"@fr-BE .
```

with **langMatches(lang(?title),"fr")**, but only the first one with **lang(?title) = "fr"**.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `rdfs:label` for a name, of course all the names are English, you are looking at the English dbpedia.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
    ?person a owl:Person .
    ?person rdfs:label ?name . 
    FILTER(lang(?name) = "fr")
}
```

Again, for the second one, if you replace the name with the `rdfs: label` you can have:

```
    PREFIX owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    SELECT distinct *
        WHERE {
    ?person a owl:Person .
    ?person rdfs:label ?name .
    ?person dbpprop:language <http://dbpedia.org/resource/English_language>.
}
```

Comment: Running `select ?label { dbpedia:England rdfs:label ?label }` on http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ returns [twelve different results](http://goo.gl/ZGVXrB) and only one is in English.  It's not so clear that "**You are looking for rdfs:label for a name, of course all the names are English**".

Comment: And it's better to use `langMatches(lang(?name),"fr")` than `lang(?name) = "fr"`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any detailed documents on these properties?  The official ontology hierarchy(such as http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Person) only contains some simple comments.

Comment: @Tilney The properties in `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` are from the DBpedia ontology and typically have much cleaner values than the properties in `http://dbpedia.org/property/`, which are much closed to the raw infobox data.  Have a look at [4.3 Infobox data](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h434-10).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm checking on the ontology page. By the way, does dbpedia sparql endpoint limit the size of the result set? I can only get 10,001 records even after I increase the time-out field.