# SPARQL DbPedia foaf:name

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, foaf

Trying to execute some queries but when searching for foaf:name resultset is empty. Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri ?string 
WHERE {
    ?uri rdf:type ?x.       
        ?uri foaf:name 'Cavallo domestico'@it   .
        OPTIONAL { ?uri rdfs:label ?string . FILTER (lang(?string) = 'it') }
}
```

page exist http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Equus_caballus/html

Apparently seems it's not related with languages different than english but with foaf:name request. If I execute following, retrieving generic foaf:givenName, it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri ?string 
WHERE {
    ?uri rdf:type ?x.       
        ?uri foaf:givenName 'Jimmy'@en   .
        OPTIONAL { ?uri rdfs:label ?string . FILTER (lang(?string) = 'en') }
}
```

Comment: Did you run this against http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql ? It works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dbpedia fetch entitites in language other than english](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069479/dbpedia-fetch-entitites-in-language-other-than-english)

Comment: which one? the first, the second or both? First query returns no results if run in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/.
If run in it.dbpedia.org/sparql , as you suggest, it works.....

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure it's a duplicate anymore.  When I look at the Horse entry on DBpedia, I only see one rdfs:label, now.  When I pull down the corresponding NTriples, I *do* get all the labels, but I don't seem them on dbpedia.org/sparql when I query for rdfs:label.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor When I run the query [click](http://bit.ly/1S4zD5v) I get all labels from dbpedia.org/sparql .

Comment: @AKSW Yup, it's definitely there.  I'm pretty sure it wasn't showing up when I did that search, but maybe I had a typo or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this wasn't working when I first mentioned that it didn't [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755171/sparql-dbpedia-foafname?noredirect=1#comment55283467_33755171), but, [as AKSW points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755171/sparql-dbpedia-foafname/33788164#comment55341574_33755171), this seems to be working now.  The rdfs:label property has the article titles in various languages, not the foaf:name, so you can do this to get the types of Horse:

```sql
select ?x ?type {
  ?x a ?type ;
     rdfs:label "Equus caballus"@it
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fx%20%3Ftype%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx%20a%20%3Ftype%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Equus%20caballus%22%40it%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: yes it works
the problem is in the endpoint you query:
In: dbpedia.org/snorql it doesn't 
In: it.dbpedia.org/sparql it does!